# MudAutoComplete can only show 10 results?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I have at least a dozen items which should be populating my MudAutoComplete but I am only seeing the first 10 results. I found in the https://www.mudblazor.com/components/autocomplete#presentation-extras documentation where they explain how to define a `<MoreItemsTemplate>`. And they state that only the first ten items are shown but there is no mention of how to increase this value.

```html
<MudItem xs="12" sm="3">
    <MudAutocomplete Value="TeamFilter" ValueChanged="OnTeamValueChanged" @ref="teamAutocomplete" T="Team" Label="Team" SearchFunc="@SearchTeam" ToStringFunc="@(e => e == null ? null : $"{e.Name}")" Class="mt-1" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" Adornment="Adornment.End" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" AdornmentColor="Color.Primary" ProgressIndicatorColor="Color.Default" Dense="true" ResetValueOnEmptyText="true" CoerceText="true">
        <NoItemsTemplate>
            <MudText Align="Align.Center" Class="px-4 py-1">
                No teams found
            </MudText>
        </NoItemsTemplate>
    </MudAutocomplete>
</MudItem>
```

Comment: The MaxItems is working for me: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GkwdPlvJHONmOsBw .
What is your MaxTeamLength?

Answer (score 1):

Within the component https://www.mudblazor.com/api/autocomplete#properties properties I found that the attribute `MaxItems` when set to `null` will display all items. Its default value is 10.